# How can I view the contents of Varnish's hash_data()?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I know that in Varnish you can add data to the cache hash using hash_data() within vcl_hash, as per the [docs](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html).

For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to see the entire contents of whatever is making up the hash.

For example, it would be really useful if we could do:

```
 # This won't work:
 set req.http.X-DEBUG = "HASH-DATA:" + hash_data();
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: `varnishlog` properly explains what hash data is used for that specific request. Is that not sufficient - gathering the data from there?

Comment: @debreczeni-andrás Yes that worked nicely for me, thanks. If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Just had the exact same question. It seems that returning headers such as req.http.X-DEBUG is exactly what you'd want to do.  Logging is outside the flow of debugging one webpage result, and not as convenient.   Response headers are great.    Is hash_data() readable? Could it be made readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varnishlog` properly explains what hash data is used for a specific request.

You can redirect the varnishlog output to your custom file for further review:

```
varnishlog > my-log.log
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore with Varnish 5. Am I supposed to see Hash data with varnishlog because I don't see anything other than the VCL_call to HASH and the VCL_return hash. There is no tag named Hash available.

Answer (score 11):

You can usually see it with the `varnishlog` command.

However, since varnish 5 you need to enable the hash specifically in the log output. This can be done with the `varnishadm` utility:

Execute `varnishadm` and on the prompt it starts, type:

```
varnish> param.set vsl_mask +Hash
```

you can exit the shell by typing `quit`, and then run `varnishlog` again, it should display the hash used on each request now.

Comment: And in an oneliner: `sudo varnishadm param.set vsl_mask +Hash`